# Is there a way to unwrap a mesh without scaling the UVs to match the aspect ratio of the texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there a way to use *Project from view* without the resulting UVs scaled to match the aspect ratio of the image?

For example, if I unwrap with *Project from view* the result looks like this:

[image]

I want it to be exactly how the mesh appears in the 3D view, e.g.:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Plain *UV Unwrap* and *Project from View* commands have the option **Correct Aspect** to take into account currently displayed image's aspect ratio. The image must already be opened and displayed in the Image Editor before unwrapping.

**EDIT:** It seems this feature only works correctly, when the active render engine is anything *but* **Cycles**.

Checking **Orthographic** also avoids perspective distortion if you happen to unwrap from *Ortho* view:

[image: 1a]

*Ortho* or not, the resulting UV map is always of the right proportion by using **Correct Aspect**, even on images with aspect ratio far from 1:1 (this one after scaling down the UV map proportionally):

[image: 2a]

Comment: Strange.. *Correct Aspect* is enabled by default, however the result is scaled regardless if it is enabled or not. Perhaps a bug? Tested on linux with 2.68a and 2.69.

Comment: @gandalf3: I also tested on those versions (in Ubuntu) with images of various aspect ratio, and **Correct Aspect** worked fine for all of them. Can't figure out what goes wrong in your case.

Comment: I'm on Arch, but I tested with the official builds from blender.org.. Could you upload a .blend? [Here's the one I've been testing with](http://pasteall.org/blend/25398).

Comment: Here's my [test blendfile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25400). In the file, I tried Project from View on a plane and a cube, and it worked correctly on both. Tried yours, and curiously it doesn't work on that image. Maybe it has something to do with image format, still testing it.

Comment: @gandalf3: I linked the image in your test file to mine, and unwrapping the objects using its aspect ratio  works. There's gotta be some different setting in your test file.

Comment: @gandalf3: **Correct Aspect** doesn't work when the active render engine is **Cycles**. That's very unexpected. Will update my answer.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, added a [report](http://developer.blender.org/T37610).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is caused because there is no material setup for the plane object.

From this [bug report](http://developer.blender.org/T37610):

> Correct aspect for Cycles uses material's image, not face texture (because Cycles doesn't have face textures).
>
> In your ca[s]e [the plane] doesn't have any materials. If you'll create new material for [the plane] and use 100.png as Image Texture for it aspect correction will go fine for you.